# Android Architecture Component + Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

Пишу приложение, использую Android Architecture Component.
У меня возникает проблема при написании Repository, я получаю ответ с помощью Retrofit

```
class HamstersRepository {
    private var webService: IWebService ?= null

    fun getHamsters(): LiveData<Hamsters>{
        val data = MutableLiveData<Hamsters>()
        webService!!.getHamsters().enqueue(object: Callback<Hamsters>{
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Hamsters>, response: Response<Hamsters>) {
                data.value(response.body())   //ошибка
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Hamsters>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e("Ошибка:", t.message)
            }

        })
        return data
    }
}
```

Ошибка:

```
Expression 'value' of type 'Hamsters?' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found
```

Как можно исправить?

Пишу по статье [Ссылка](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide) только на Kotlin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оказывается теперь value не метод, а свойство:

```
data.value =response.body()
```